# How do I load an XML document in a SUN One ASP hosting environment in Linux

Tags: xml, asp-classic

I am working on an ASP site hosted using SUN One (used to be called Chillisoft) server. I am having trouble loading in an XML file, the code I am using is below

```
dim directory
set directory = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

if(directory.load(Server.MapPath("directory.xml"))) then
     Response.Write("Loaded")
else
     Response.Write("NotLoaded")
    If directory.parseError.errorCode Then
        Response.Write( "Parse error" )
    end if
end if
```

My asp page and directory.xml are both in the same folder "/public_html/".

I think the problem might have something to do with the mappath not finding the file, but no errors are returned so not sure what to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Sun One but I do know it has a Bean that emulates MSXML.

Oridinarily, you would use:-

```
Set directory = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
directory.async = false
directory.load(Server.MapPath("directory.xml")
```

Otherwise load returns immeadiately whilst the xml is loaded asynchronously.

It can't see how the code you have posted would not return something without error.

First diagnositic I would is:-

```
Response.Write(Server.MapPath("directory.xml"))
```

and then

```
Dim direcotory
Set directory = Server.CreateObject("MSXML.DOMDocument")
Response.Write(Not (directory Is Nothing))
```

Answer (score 0):

The load likely returns false because it hasn't fully loaded the document yet.  You need to find a way to set async to false.  If the Sun One is emulating MSXML2.DOMDocument well then async should accept false but you could try -`1` or `Response.Write(directory.async)` to get an idea of what it is originally set to.